# Use current working directory as path with AWS Cli

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cmd, aws-cli

I'm attempting to sync my bucket from my local directory using AWS Cli on Windows.

It works using the command

`aws s3 sync C:\[long path name] s3://[bucket name]`

I would prefer to replace the path name with something shorter or just associate it with the bucket. I've tried `chdir` and `cd`. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: How about using a short symbolic link to the long path name?

Comment: Just made an edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wish to synchronize the current directory to an Amazon S3 bucket, use:

```
aws s3 sync . s3://[bucket name]
```

Or to sync to a directory within the S3 bucket:

```
aws s3 sync . s3://[bucket name]/[path]
```

The same syntax works on Windows and Linux.